# Ext.form.Panel on top of a Toolbar has some white space around it

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have the following situation. I have an `Ext.form.field.File` (With the `buttonOnly: true` on top of a `Ext.form.Panel` which is on top of a Toolbar docked on an `Ext.grid.Panel`. The result of that is, the button has a completely different style then the toolbar, and the Panel seems to have some white space around button that you can see. Anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this, so that the style of the button and panel matches the toolbar (I use default styles, didn't modify anything).

EDIT: here is some code:

```
upload_button = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.File', {
            buttonOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Upload File",
            hideLabel: true,
            listeners: {..}

        });

        button_panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            region: 'south',
            items: upload_button
        });


  upload_toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',{
            width: 400,
            region: 'north',
            dock: 'top',
            items: [ button_panel]});

grid_file = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'File List',
            region: 'center',
            height: 300,
            store: store_file,
            dockedItems: [upload_toolbar],
```

Comment: I'm not sure 'on top' is clear enough. You are far more likely to get an answer if you provide some code and a screen shot. It sounds odd, so I assume it's just a misconfig, but the solution might require some css hack.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said 'inside of'? Not quite sure how to term it right.

Comment: Yes. 'Inside of' sounds much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using regions, but I cannot see any `border` layout.

Your problem is that you are trying to put a panel within a toolbar - it won't work.

You better off just putting an hidden upload form somewhere in your page; putting a normal button in the toolbar, and have the toolbar button press triggering a press on the hidden form.

So this would be the hidden upload form definition:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Assignments' ,
{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.assignments-panel',

    hidden: true,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        id: 'uploadField',
        emptyText: 'Select a file',
        fieldLabel: 'Assignment',
        name: 'assignment-path',
        buttonText: '...',
        buttonConfig: {
            iconCls: 'upload-icon'
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'hidden',
        id:    'submissionIdField',
        name:  'submissionId',
        value: ''
    }],
});
```

And then when the visible update button is pressed you can do:

```
var uploadField = Ext.getCmp( 'uploadField' );
uploadField.fileInputEl.dom.click();
```

Comment: That worked really well. If you have a moment can you look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746671/how-to-get-an-extjs-application-to-look-like-the-feed-example