# How to get an ExtJs application to look like the Feed Example?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In my ExtJS Applications I have 3 components, an  `Ext.tree.Panel`, and `Ext.grid.Panel` and an `Ext.Img`. I want them to have the same layout as the Feed Viewer example here:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html

I have been trying to look at the code but I am still having trouble getting my components to look like that (One component on the left, and two on the right one on top of the other). Can anyone explain how I can do this using 'Border' layout? (Which is what it looks like they are using).

EDIT: tried creating a Nested Border Layout. The `Ext.tree.Panel` on the left and a `Ext.tab.Panel` on the right with the `Ext.grid.Panel` and the `Ext.Img` inside of it. This causes the entire tab panel to show up blank. Code below:

```
 grid_file = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'File List',
            region: 'north',
            height:200,
            width:700, 
            store: store_file,
            dockedItems: [upload_toolbar],
            columns: [..]});

var imagePanel = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
            src: 'DefaultImage',
            region: 'south',
            width: 700,
            height: 200
        });
 var tab_Panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel' , {
            width: 700,
            region: 'center',
            items: [grid_file, imagePanel]})

        win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'ExtJS Simple File Browser',
            width: 900,
            height: 400,
            layout: 'border',
            bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
            items: [tree_dir,button_panel]
        });

        win.show();
```

Comment: The window with border layout has tree_dir and button_panel as items, where are these define? and what is the container of all the panels that has regions? If grid_file has region, it's container (tab_panel) must have a border layout.

Comment: tree_dir is an `Ext.tree.Panel` and button_panel is an `Ext.form.Panel`. I added `layout: 'border'` to tab_panel. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Silly error, I didn't add the tab_panel to win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a nested border layout:

You have the main layout, which is border with:

- West: The feeds
- Center: The feed info panel

And the feed info panel has border layout as well with:

- Center: The grid.
- South:  The selected feed.

The code of the feedviewer is somewhat involved. You will probably find [this](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) more helpful.

Submit your code if you still can't work it out.

Comment: Hmm, added some code. The Panel I added for the nested layout appears blank.

Answer (score 0):

Open developer console in Chrome. And check sources. They are not compressed and readable. :) Viewport created in FeedViewer class. So this is your entry point.